# Angular controller's attribute not accessible outside its function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form with two input fields (`session.email` and `session.psw`) bound to the `LoginController.session` attribute. When I click the reset button, I call the `LoginController.reset()`  function.

I would like make it clear the session attribute, utilizing the variable `sessionDefault (empty)`. However it works just one time, if I reset two times the form, `sessionDefault` is `undefined`.

How could I make it as a constant attribute of the controller?

```
  app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope)
        {
         this.session={};
         var sessionDefault=
              {
                  email : "",
                  psw: ""
              };    

         this.reset = function()
                {  this.session = sessionDefault;  };                       
        });
```

Comment: it is not an answer, it doesn't work. It is just my not-working code

Comment: The comments I commented about got removed, sorry

Comment: oh.. ok, never mind  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this out

for reset function just reset it with sessionDefault copy like as shown below

```
vm.reset = function () {
    vm.session = angular.copy(sessionDefault);
};
```

here `this` refers to the controller instance

Notice that I use `var vm = this;` and then I decorate `vm` with the members that should be exposed and data-bindable to to the View. `vm` simply denotes `view modal`

This does 3 things for me.

- Provides a consistent and readable method of creating bindings in my controllers
- Removes any issues of dealing with this scoping or binding (i.e. closures in nested functions)
- Removes `$scope` from the controller unless I explicitly need it for something else

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gfqf7rLL/)**

**script**

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope) {
     var vm = this;
     vm.session = {};
     var sessionDefault = {
        email: "",
        psw: ""
     };
     vm.reset = function () {
         vm.session = angular.copy(sessionDefault);
     };
});
```

**html**

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="LoginController as login">
    Email:<input type="text" ng-model="login.session.email"/>{{login.session.email}}
    <br>
    Psw:<input type="text" ng-model="login.session.psw"/>{{login.session.psw}}
    <br>
    <button ng-click="login.reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Take a look at this beautiful stuff.

**[AngularJS’s Controller As and the vm Variable](http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)**

Comment: this code works as mine, it resets just one time. At the second resent, it doesn't work anymore

Comment: @DeLac I have updated my answer, check that working demo

Comment: now it works! great... thank you.  So I need `vm.session = angular.copy(sessionDefault)` instead of `vm.session = sessionDefault`   I wonder to know why..  I didn't know this function.

Comment: @DeLac [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) is a kind of deep copy feature provided by angularjs

Answer (score 0):

```
this.reset = function()
                {  this.session = sessionDefault;  };
```

The `this` in this context refers to the function (`reset`). If you want to access the 'original' `this` you need to store it in a variable.

```
 app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope)
        {
         this.session={};
         var sessionDefault=
              {
                  email : "",
                  psw: ""
              };    

         var self = this;
         this.reset = function()
                {  self.session = angular.clone( sessionDefault);  };                       
        });
```

Comment: it makes sense. however, as other solutions, it works just one time. I can't figure out why..

Comment: according to @Nidhish, it seems that _angular.copy(sessionDefault)_ is needed